# send json data object with notification from FCM (V1) problem with sending Authorization (Request had invalid authentication credentials)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send json data with notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) with postman tool but I getting this error message

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

even though I setting OAuth 2.0 Client IDs sucessfully

[image]

the post link

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dummy-app-kotlin/messages:send
```

```
Content-Type = application/json
```

```
Authorization = Bearer AAAAeLOYqUQ:AP=....  ====> the problem happens hear
```

I tried to follow this [instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=en&authuser=0) **Update authorization of send requests** to set Authorization, in old version it was used like the following

```
Authorization: key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

in the new one (Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
```

I tried to add `Bearer` with old server key and `Bearer ya29.API_KEY` but all this tries fails

```
Authorization: Bearer=AAAAeLOYqUQ:APA91b....

Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
```

This How I used it in postman

[image]

the Body of message

```
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      

      "kind": "blogger#post",
"id": "6267138061295984555",
"blog": {
"id": "4294497614198718393"
},
"published": "2022-10-01T21:16:00-07:00",
"updated": "2022-10-01T21:16:20-07:00",
"url": "http://abtallaldigital.blogspot.com/2022/10/test-address-for-educational-purposes.html",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4294497614198718393/posts/6267138061295984555",
"title": "Test Address for educational purposes ",
"content": "<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEiW9-kPP-UsOPV-NgPTQDML5pxk2aIRIKb39d1ZKXhQ12afwCRpcgYMmmuPZZ_Xtdmhu6gdfd9RCoUqROdK6wyeGASpGBTnte6qHe8XKWUutT0KU9UGHEO2OsRjUh6YSmRahsxO6a9J7NVU8NKpluZXfTiVEmBOz4yVS3ioFzcMzEGW80A_W36lVBiD/s639/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%B9.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="400" data-original-width="639" src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEiW9-kPP-UsOPV-NgPTQDML5pxk2aIRIKb39d1ZKXhQ12afwCRpcgYMmmuPZZ_Xtdmhu6gdfd9RCoUqROdK6wyeGASpGBTnte6qHe8XKWUutT0KU9UGHEO2OsRjUh6YSmRahsxO6a9J7NVU8NKpluZXfTiVEmBOz4yVS3ioFzcMzEGW80A_W36lVBiD/s16000/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%B9.jpg" /></a></div><div style="text-align: left;"><br /></div><p style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ultricies, sem eu finibus placerat, lacus felis pharetra augue, id malesuada ante lorem eget risus. In a feugiat libero. Duis sed tempor massa, non porttitor mi. Ut odio nisl, accumsan ut purus id, facilisis pulvinar lectus. Mauris semper metus dolor, sed efficitur nulla porttitor eget. Mauris posuere lacinia faucibus. Quisque tortor diam, gravida ut sapien nec, viverra suscipit augue. Suspendisse ut cursus leo. Vestibulum sem lectus, consectetur sit amet tempus tempus, accumsan dictum orci. Sed at ex magna. Nulla facilisi. Sed vulputate vulputate magna quis sollicitudin. Pellentesque tempus leo mauris, non sodales nunc commodo eget. Nullam blandit dictum posuere.</p><p style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Integer sodales lorem urna, id sodales turpis suscipit laoreet. Mauris efficitur, nisl et malesuada iaculis, dolor tortor dictum ante, sit amet maximus ipsum sem quis nunc. Maecenas ut fermentum elit. Phasellus interdum venenatis dolor, eget molestie dui tempus et. Vivamus euismod in ligula at placerat. Maecenas nec mauris vel urna lacinia semper nec blandit ante. Nunc mauris dui, gravida vitae sapien a, tristique mattis diam. In vel erat hendrerit, aliquam nibh ut, accumsan est. Nulla non dui erat. Duis eleifend tincidunt est. Aenean euismod sodales semper.</p><p style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">In et magna vitae metus ultricies tincidunt nec et enim. Suspendisse fermentum quis elit eget molestie. Ut vitae neque nibh. Praesent fermentum sem eget arcu faucibus, vel tristique leo dictum. Proin vestibulum urna et scelerisque euismod. Vivamus nunc tellus, consectetur vel blandit at, fringilla ut mi. Donec gravida, nisl et varius ullamcorper, est sapien efficitur mi, sit amet hendrerit felis felis ac tellus. Sed porttitor ante nec neque efficitur dictum.</p><p style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Nullam sit amet massa fringilla felis pretium ultricies ac non leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque rhoncus congue erat quis condimentum. Integer nulla arcu, porttitor in eleifend sed, lacinia sed orci. Aenean scelerisque nulla nec vulputate ullamcorper. Mauris faucibus erat eget arcu vulputate, et euismod nunc cursus. Mauris imperdiet purus sit amet tellus ultrices viverra.</p><p style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Duis consectetur fringilla arcu, a mollis neque porttitor eget. Aenean vitae elit eleifend, pellentesque metus sed, commodo tellus. Suspendisse vitae metus in ipsum cursus bibendum ac in purus. Maecenas faucibus quam eget justo efficitur, quis convallis justo ornare. Curabitur sit amet eros a ante pretium venenatis in ut ante. Etiam tincidunt diam vel porta dignissim. Integer accumsan varius nisi nec hendrerit. Fusce venenatis ante nisl, a suscipit dolor sagittis a.</p>",
"author": {
"id": "08422403953887176873",
"displayName": "Mido Man",
"url": "https://www.blogger.com/profile/08422403953887176873",
"image": {
"url": "//4.bp.blogspot.com/-8e0LEXIezAg/XUR1urMX6uI/AAAAAAAAIBA/Wv9C5LxnRmwmOKemppsEHlcAw3kRrrQKQCK4BGAYYCw/s35/Java.png"
}
},
"replies": {
"totalItems": "0",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4294497614198718393/posts/6267138061295984555/comments"
},
"etag": ""dGltZXN0YW1wOiAxNjY0Njg0MTgwODEyCm9mZnNldDogLTI1MjAwMDAwCg""

    }
  }
```

Both Cloud Messaging APIs (V1) &  enabled

[image: Cloud Messaging APIs]

Comment: did u find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: @demonjoseph no, as you see, no answers!

Answer (score 2):

Your headers and body of your post is correct.
You should exchange your authorization code for tokens.

Here is how you can test

1 - Open OAuth 2.0 Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

2- Input your scope which is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging
(After you submit your scope it is gonna authorize to your google account)

3- Enter your authorization code (device's token which is given by firebase when u did your configuration for your UI)  and click "Exchange authorization code for token"

Playground will give you access token and refresh token. You should put your access token like **Bearer ya29...** .

After you able to send notification with postman.
But for your software you should automate exchanging tokens in your code.

For automating you need your firebase credentials from
Project Settings > Service Accounts > Generate new private key (below Firebase Admin SDK )
After that you will get your google-services.json which as your keys to automate your authorization.

Check out this repo for your programming language .

https://github.com/googleapis?q=auth

Comment: I followed the steps but the playground tool give me the access token with **Bearer** at the first like that `ya29.a0Aa4xr....` so I copied it and put **Bearer** before it in Authorization in postman but I got different error this once `"code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\ntent\": \"<div class=\"separator\" style=\"cl\n                    ^",`

Comment: Keep your body simple at first.

`{
"message":{
"token":"<device's token (before you authenticated)",
"notification":{
"body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
"title":"FCM Message",
//"image":""
}
}
}`
Try like this

Comment: You handled OAuth2 problem, it says your body incorrect with that error

Comment: I got the same message with your test body `{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected an object key or }.\n//\"image\":\"\" } }\n^",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}` so I deleted this two // and it's worked but I got error related with key again

Comment: this the new error `{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: Your token has 24 hours expiration time. You need to take another token again.

Comment: Which token you mean? in playground tool there are two tokens, **Refresh token** and **Access token** and the last one refresh it self every 3595 seconds, please see this [image](https://i.imgur.com/OX9dN6a.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248832/discussion-between-dr-mido-and-demonjoseph).

Comment: please check last message in the chat, thanks